# Galaxy Nexus: how to upload music in Linux?

Tags: music, samsung-galaxy-nexus

As you know, Galaxy Nexus supports only MTP protocol for USB connection, which is not greatly supported under Linux. As a workaround, I have tried to upload my music to Galaxy Nexus through WiFi. I have installed "WebDAV server" (The Olive Tree) from Market and uploaded a couple of tracks to Music folder. But, Music app on the phone does not see any music, shows just "ways to add music..." message. Is there a way to force a rescan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific solution for my problem is to install [Rescan SD application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uberullu.rescansd) from Market and launch it after uploading music through WebDAV.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/), instead of your WebDav work-a-round. 
I tried every way and this is by far the best.

Answer (score -1):

I have to admit I have not played with Galaxy Nexus, but  [AIRDOID](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) is claimed to be a good solution for moving files. I use it with both my phones and works fine. I know the new way parts are mounted makes a huge difference. I usually use Zimly as media player, and it finds uploded with airdroid files without any problems. You might need to re-scan media, as well.

If you are on Ubuntu, you might try [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/galaxy-nexus/) as last resort solution

Comment: After buying and using Nexus for an year, I can confirm that webdroid is valid alternative. It wont mount your phone, but will allow wirelessly to copy music and an other file